# Passing output stream object and other arguments to multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, ofstream

I'm trying to pass multiple arguments, one of which is an `ofstream` object, to multiple threads using the `C++11` standard.

I want to pass an `ofstream` object because I want every thread to write in a different output file.

I'm initializing the threads and output streams in this way:

```
std::thread execution_threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; // creating multiple empty threads
std::ofstream output_files[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; // Empty output streams
// Opening and initializing the output files
```

Each thread executes a function that takes two arguments:

```
void execution(int thread_id, std::ofstream& output_file)
```

So I've looked around and I've read that in `C++11` when a function `func` has multiple arguments `a,b,c,d` there's no need to use a `struct` and you can pass them just by writing `std::thread t(func, a,b,c,d);`. So I wrote this loop in order to launch the threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < utils::NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
    execution_threads[i] = std::thread(execution, i, output_files[i]);
}
```

The thing is that this code doesn't compile with this error:

```
Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
'typename decay<basic_ofstream<char, char_traits<char> > &>::type'
(aka 'std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >')
```

While if I use a `struct` as input in this way, everything works fine:

```
// Struct definition
struct thread_input {
    int thread_id;
    std::ofstream& output_file;
};

// This is the function that now has only one argument
void execution(struct thread_input input)

// And this is the loop that launches the threads
for (int i = 0; i < utils::NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
    struct thread_input input = {i, output_files[i]};
    execution_threads[i] = std::thread(execution, input);
}

// join() functions for each thread and end of the program
```

In this way everything works fine it compiles and it runs perfectly. But I really don't get why the compiler tells me that I'm trying to use the deleted copy-constructor if I use the other method.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::thread` stores a copy of its arguments.  When you pass it a non-copyable object like a `std::ofstream` it will complain.

You have two options:

1) Don't store an array of `std::ofstream` objects; just let your threads store their own streams.  In this case, there's no need to copy the stream (just a move, which is fine):

```
for (int i = 0; i < utils::NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
    execution_threads[i] = std::thread(execution, i, std::ofstream{});
                                                   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ anonymous temporary
}
```

Of course, in this case you could just have the thread construct its own stream (maybe just pass in the filename).

2) Pass a `std::reference_wrapper<std::ofstream>` to your thread.  `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is an object that holds a reference to `T` and has an implicit conversion to `T&`, so you'll just end up copying the reference instead of the stream itself.  You can use the `std::ref` factory to deduce `T` and reduce typing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < utils::NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
    execution_threads[i] = std::thread(execution, i, std::ref(output_files[i]));
                                                   //^^^^^^^^ std::ref added
}
```

This leaves you with all of the same ownership and lifetime issues that passing a struct containing a `std::ofstream&` would have (after all, that's all `std::reference_wrapper` is).  It's up to you to make sure your `output_files` array survives until all of your threads have finished with it.